# Spring Boot Actuator Endpoints security doesn't work with custom Spring Security Configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-boot-actuator

This is my Spring Boot 1.5.1 Actuator `application.properties`:

```
#Spring Boot Actuator
management.contextPath: /actuator
management.security.roles=R_0
```

This is my `WebSecurityConfig`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Value("${logout.success.url}")
    private String logoutSuccessUrl;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        // @formatter:off
        http.addFilterBefore(new CorsFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class);

        http
            .csrf().ignoringAntMatchers("/v1.0/**", "/logout")
        .and()
            .authorizeRequests()

            .antMatchers("/oauth/authorize").authenticated()
            //Anyone can access the urls
            .antMatchers("/signin/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/v1.0/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/actuator/health").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/actuator/**").hasAuthority("R_0")
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .failureUrl("/login?error=true")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .permitAll()
            .and()
                .logout()
                    .logoutUrl("/logout")
                    .logoutSuccessUrl(logoutSuccessUrl)
                    .permitAll();
        // @formatter:on
    }

    /**
     * Configures the authentication manager bean which processes authentication requests.
     */
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

}
```

Right now I'm successfully able to login in my application with a right user that has `R_0` authorities but when I trying to access for example

```
http://localhost:8080/api/actuator/beans
```

I receive a following error:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
Access is denied. User must have one of the these roles: R_0
```

How to correctly configure Spring Boot Actuator in order to be aware about the correct `Authentication` ?

Right now in order to get it workin I have to do the following trick:

```
management.security.enabled=false

.antMatchers("/actuator/health").permitAll()
.antMatchers("/actuator/**").hasAuthority("R_0")
```

Is any chance to configure Actuator in a right way ?

**UPDATED**

I'm using `UserDetailsService.UserDetails.Authorities`

```
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        String[] authorities = permissions.stream().map(p -> {
            return p.getName();
        }).toArray(String[]::new);
        return AuthorityUtils.createAuthorityList(authorities);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm able to manage this with `.antMatchers("/actuator/**").hasAuthority("R_0")`. The issue is that I'm unable to get working the default Spring Boot Actuator security integration with no needs to provide a custom configs like a this one.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Noticed that by setting a `UserDetailsService` on `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` somehow overrides the default security config meaning a need for an explicit URI access configuration like you did via `HttpSecurity` class. Have you managed to make it work as you originally expected?

Comment: Yes, you have to use prefix `ROLE_` for your `management.security.roles`  for example  `management.security.roles=ROLE_SOMENAME`

Comment: Since I'm on Spring Boot 1.3.5, my problem was related to plural vs singular format of this property. For my version you can only define one role as, e.g. `management.security.role=ACTUATOR`, which was changed in versions 1.4.x to the plural equivalent. Besides, I combined two sources for `UserDetails` retrieval for `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` class, one is an implementation of `UserDetailsService` for my service users and the second is an instance of `InMemoryUserDetailsManagerConfigurer` for actuator and admin users (you can get away with only one too).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use prefix `ROLE_` for your `management.security.roles` for example  `management.security.roles=ROLE_SOMENAME` in order to solve this issue

Comment: I thought in Spring Boot 1.5.1 the values of  `management.security.roles` property shouldn't be prefixed with `ROLE_` anymore. I found a lot of confusion concerning this subject. I believe your problem could also be fixed by modifying the following `HttpSecurity` settings `.antMatchers("/actuator/**").hasAuthority("ROLE_R_0")` instead.

Comment: antMatcher doesn't solve the problem. For examle actuator/health endpoint returns different data for authorized and not authorized user. It is impossible to implement based on the provided antMatcher configuration

Comment: The behaviour you're talking about is documented in section 48.7 of http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html. Your original question was about 403 status code for `/actuator/beans` call. I believe it can be fixed by removing both `antMatchers("/actuator...")` settings and ensuring the `UserDetailsService` returns a `UserDetails` object containing `GrantedAuthority` set to `ROLE_R_0` in your case. Alternatively, you could combine it with `InMemoryUserDetailsManagerConfigurer` as I mentioned in the comment to the main question.

Comment: It doesn't work because Spring Boot Actuator doesn't understand authorities/roles without _ROLE prefix. Also antMatchers doesn't help here because in order to use it I have to disable management.security. With disabling this property I'll lose Actuator functionality like I have described above so your solution completely doesn't have any sense to me.

Comment: for more details refer the following github issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/8255

Answer (score 0):

To have authorization to spring boot actuator endpoints you need to have **ACTUATOR** role.
Refer this example [Accessing Restricted Actuator Endpoints with Spring Security](http://www.devglan.com/faq/spring-boot-actuator-rest-endpoints-example/#/enable-security-to-endpoints)

Answer (score 0):

I'm coming at this from a Reactive Spring Boot 2.x app and had this problem and solved it by updating the WebSecurityConfig.securityWebFilterChain as well as SecurityContextRepository.load to include /actuator/** as follows:

```
public class WebSecurityConfig {
  private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

  private SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository;

  @Autowired
  public WebSecurityConfig(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager, SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository) {
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    this.securityContextRepository = securityContextRepository;
  }

  @Bean
  public SecurityWebFilterChain securityWebFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    return http
      .exceptionHandling()
      .authenticationEntryPoint((swe, e) -> Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
        swe.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
      })).accessDeniedHandler((swe, e) -> Mono.fromRunnable(() -> {
        swe.getResponse().setStatusCode(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
      })).and()
      .csrf().disable()
      .formLogin().disable()
      .httpBasic().disable()
      .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
      .securityContextRepository(securityContextRepository)
      .authorizeExchange()
      .pathMatchers("/actuator/**").permitAll()
      .anyExchange().authenticated()
      .and().build();
  }
```

as well as updating

```
@Slf4j
@Component
public class SecurityContextRepository implements ServerSecurityContextRepository {

  private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

  public SecurityContextRepository(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
    this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
  }

  @Override
  public Mono<Void> save(ServerWebExchange swe, SecurityContext sc) {
    return Mono.error(new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported"));
  }

  @Override
  public Mono<SecurityContext> load(ServerWebExchange swe) {
    ServerHttpRequest request = swe.getRequest();

    if (request.getPath().value().startsWith("/actuator") ) {
      return Mono.empty();
    }
    // other authentication logic here
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
1
1.You can add the following properties
endpoints.health.enabled=true
endpoints.loggers.enabled=true
endpoints.metrics.enabled=true

endpoints.env.enabled=false
endpoints.configprops.enabled=false
endpoints.autoconfig.enabled=false
endpoints.info.enabled=false

management.context-path=/management

2)
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static final String ACTUATOR = "ACTUATOR";
    private static final String ROLE1 = "USER";

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/controllerpath/**")
                .hasAnyRole(ROLE1).antMatchers("/loggers/**","/metrics/**","/health/**").hasAnyRole(ACTUATOR).and()

                .csrf().disable().headers().frameOptions().disable();

    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder())
                .withUser("username-of-app").password("encryptedpassword")
                .roles(ROLE1).and().withUser("username-of-management-for-path")
                .password("encrypted password").roles(ACTUATOR);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can add the following properties

```
    endpoints.health.enabled=true
    endpoints.loggers.enabled=true
    endpoints.metrics.enabled=true
    
    endpoints.env.enabled=false
    endpoints.configprops.enabled=false
    endpoints.autoconfig.enabled=false
    endpoints.info.enabled=false
    
    management.context-path=/management
```

2. 

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements ApplicationContextAware {
    
        private static final String ACTUATOR = "ACTUATOR";
        private static final String ROLE1 = "USER";
    
        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http.httpBasic().and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/controllerpath/**")
                    .hasAnyRole(ROLE1).antMatchers("/loggers/**","/metrics/**","/health/**").hasAnyRole(ACTUATOR).and()
    
                    .csrf().disable().headers().frameOptions().disable();
    
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    
            auth.inMemoryAuthentication().passwordEncoder(new BCryptPasswordEncoder())
                    .withUser("username-of-app").password("encryptedpassword")
                    .roles(ROLE1).and().withUser("username-of-management-for-path")
                    .password("encrypted password").roles(ACTUATOR);
    
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

According to this link:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-monitoring.html

> By default all sensitive HTTP endpoints are secured such that only
>   users that have an ACTUATOR role may access them. Security is enforced
>   using the standard HttpServletRequest.isUserInRole method.
>
> Use the management.security.roles property if you want something
>   different to ACTUATOR.

So I think all you have to do is set the following property in application.properties.

```
management.security.roles
```

Ex:

```
management.security.roles=R_0
```

Comment: Thanks, but please take a look onto my question. I have already provided `management.security.roles=R_0` The issue is that Spring Boot Actuator don't understand how to work with a current Spring Security for a some reason.