# Spring Health Actuator: Viewing full health

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, endpoint, spring-boot-actuator

I have a spring boot application that is using Oauth2 to secure the endpoints. I have endpoints.health.sensitive=true to only show the   "status": "UP" value. However, I also want to be able to view all of the detailed health values when I do an authenticated request. The issue comes when I use a token for the request that I know works, but I still receive back the unauthenticated response. Am I missing a value in my request or some other import detail? Any insight or path to take to find a solution is appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at this question. It may help you find the issue. https://stackoverflow.com/q/42142556/252344

Answer (score 0):

I decided to create a custom health controller that contains the full response and secure it with Oauth2 and make the default health actuator just turn the non auth response.